# Capture JavaScript Activity Similiar to Profiler

Tags: javascript

We have a large web application and a large base of JavaScript code behind it.  The feeling is only a fraction of the code is ever executed however it is of course always downloaded which is bad.

For step 1 I have been asked to database log the JavaScript activity and then performance tune the high volume use functions.  For step 2, eliminating the legacy code without breaking anything is for another day.  Getting the information into the database is the easy part.  ***My question is how do I track JavaScript activity globally similar to a profiler*** and without having to add additional code to all the functions and inline code execution?

I know I can add event listeners to track clicks, etc. but I don't think that will tell me if function A called function B, or if a function is on a timer running every 10 seconds, etc.  Also, many of the clicks I don't need since I just want those that execute code.  I ran an inline JavaScript test and a function call test in IE11 while running profiler and it captures exactly what I'm looking for.

***Am I stuck hoping that event listeners will give me all the activity a profiler tracks or is there something else I'm not aware of?  Much appreciated!***

***Here are the profiler results and code for the test I ran to see what IE11 profiler was capturing.  Would like to capture similar or same.***

(1) **TEST1_A** - OK, great, logged that function TEST1_A ran.

(1) **TEST1_B** - OK, great, function TEST1_A ran TEST1_B. Shows in Profile Tree.

(4) **innerHTML** - OK, did this 4 times.

(4) **nodeName** - OK, needed a node name 4 times.

(1) **onclick** - Ok, clicked a button.  Id would be nice to have.

(1) **onclick** - Ok, clicked a button.  Id would be nice to have.

(8) **target** - OK, targeted the page 8 times.

(2) **document** - Hmm, did this 4 times but only 2 count.  Clicked two buttons.  Maybe one count for each instance.

(2) **getElementById** - Same as above.

```
<div id="TEST1_A_RESULT_BUCKET">TEST1_A_RESULT_BUCKET</div>
<div id="TEST1_B_RESULT_BUCKET">TEST1_B_RESULT_BUCKET</div>
<div id="TEST2_A_RESULT_BUCKET">TEST2_A_RESULT_BUCKET</div>
<div id="TEST2_B_RESULT_BUCKET">TEST2_B_RESULT_BUCKET</div>

<!--run test 1 - Two JavaScript Functions-->
<button onclick="TEST1_A()">Execute Test 1</button><br>

<script>

    function TEST1_A() {

        document.getElementById('TEST1_A_RESULT_BUCKET').innerHTML = 'TEST1_A_RESULT_LOGGED';

        TEST1_B();
    }

    function TEST1_B() {

        document.getElementById('TEST1_B_RESULT_BUCKET').innerHTML = 'TEST1_B_RESULT_LOGGED';
    }

</script>

<!--run test 2 - Inline JavaScript-->
<button onclick="javascript: TEST2_A_RESULT_BUCKET.innerHTML = 'TEST2_A_RESULT_LOGGED'; TEST2_B_RESULT_BUCKET.innerHTML = 'TEST2_B_RESULT_LOGGED';">Execute Test 2</button>
```

Comment: What is the problem with using the profiler?

Comment: Using profiler on my machine only tracks my usage.  I need to track the usage of all our customers and store it in our database so I can then target the code that has high volume usage.

Comment: You need to instrument your JavaScript. http://google.github.io/tracing-framework/instrumenting-code.html

Comment: Hey Juan,  That's really useful to enhance an individuals development environment.  I think only when using Chrome.

Comment: Simply put, all I need is if a client clicks on a function I need to log that function name.  After logging for about 30 days the intent is to performance tune the high use functions.  In other words if I have a function that's called 500,000 times we want to make sure it's performing well so I'll spend time on that function.  All the other functions that are called rarely or not at all I won't bother with.  And, eventually delete the code that's never used.  In an attempt to keep the application lean and mean and reduce the download size.

Comment: I was hoping to do this without changing all the function code but maybe I can do a global replace and hopefully without breaking anything.  For example 'function foo () {' i'll add a funtion to it like 'function foo () { function logThisFunctionName(foo); '.  Unless I can find an event listener that will do it but I'm not finding one.

Comment: A tool like https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul can create an instrumented version of your code that will tell you line by line, function by function, how many times each was called

Comment: Also look at http://spy-js.com/

Comment: Hey Juan,  I don't think recommending a tool is the best answer here.  Like I said, I just need to track when a function is called and add the cumulative count to a log in the database in a production environment.  Adding more Javascript to an application where our goal is to eliminate unnecessary javascript is the wrong direction.  I'm looking for a lower level answer.  Possibly analyzing one of the tools is the answer.

Comment: It is not an answer, that's why I added it as a comment. It's a suggestion for you to look into. Instrumenting your code is a good way to know what lines get run the most.